# Class in header file

Tags: c++, function, header, virtual

I'm having a bit of trouble with a C++ program I'm working on. I've created an abstract class with a single pure virtual method. Since the class has no variables or implemented methods, I've stored the class in a header file without an .cpp implementation file (there isn't any need for one).

The method is:

```
virtual void handleEvent() = 0;
```

The issue is when I inherit from that class and implement the method:

```
virtual void handleEvent(); (.h file)
void handleEvent(){.....} (.cpp file)
```

I get a compiler error (using g++):

```
(.rodata._ZtV10Engine[vtable for Engine]+0x8): undefined reference to Engine::handleEvent()
```

The file is being included in the Engine header class. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you forgot to put the class qualifier in the .cpp implementation. It should probably read:

```
void Engine::handleEvent() { ... }
```

Comment: Don't worry, we all have those days.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [deus-ex-machina399](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438884/c/3438902#3438902) probably has it right, but it could also be your [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) (would have to be different compiler settings between at least 2 different .cpp files). Try using `__cdecl` or `__stdcall` (or whatever the correct name is for the g++ compiler, try looking at [this list](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html))